# java-notify a thread from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

i try to implement thread wait() and notify(), but notify method doesn't work, can you help me?
i want that the reader thread try to read from his messagebox; if the messagebox is empty the reader wait until the writer done the job. But after the notify action the reader still wait and do nothing and the writer continue his job.
this is my code (the other custom objects works fine):

```
    public class TrheadTEST {
    private static class AgentThred implements Runnable {    
        private final  String name;
        private final String category;
        private final PersonalAgentID agentID; // it has name and category 
        private AgentThred obiettivo; 
        private Thread trd; // i try to call notify for a specific thread.
        public MessageBox msgx; // each thread has a messagebox. Agent can read only her own messagebox        
        public AgentThred(String nam, String cat){
            this.name = nam;
            this.category = cat;
            this.agentID = new PersonalAgentID(this.name, this.category);
            this.msgx.setOwner(this.agentID);            
            this.msgx = new MessageBox();
        }
        public void setObj(AgentThred i) {
            this.obiettivo = i;
        }
        public void setThread(Thread i) {
            this.trd = i;
        }
        @Override
        synchronized  public void run() { 
        {
//set a message to send

        if(this.name == "Mercoledi"){
            while(true){
                // writer write a message in reader messagebox
                System.out.println("writer wrote");
                notifyAll();   //wake up the reader--doesn't work
               //sleep(500)
            }
        }
        else
            while(true){
                if(this.msgx.imEmpty()){ // if reader messagebox is empty
                    System.out.println("reader can't read");
                    wait(); //wait until writer put a message in the reader message box
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("reader can read ");
                    //read the message
                }
            }
    }
}
}
}
public static void main() {
    AgentThred agt1 = null;
    AgentThred agt2 = null;
     MessageBox msg = new MessageBox();
    }
    agt1 = new AgentThred("Mercoledi","Addams");
    agt2 = new AgentThred("Mano","Addams");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(agt1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(agt2);
    t2.start();
    t1.start();
//I need a join here? 
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider reading [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) if you are going to do multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

To wake up `agt2` from its waiting, you need to call `notifyAll` on the same object as the object used for waiting. In your case `agt2` waits on `this.wait()`, so you would need to call `agt2.notifyAll()` to wake it up.

Also note that comparing strings with `==` is not recommended even if it happens to work in your case.

So you could define a:

```
private static final Object waiter = new Object();
```

and call:

```
synchronized(waiter) {
  waiter.wait();
  //or
  waiter.invokeAll();`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a common object between the two on which you can wait and notify. Right now you are synchronizing on this instance of two different threads and thrying to say `this.wait` and `this.notify` and hence its not working.

For wait and notify to work, you need to obtain mutex on the same object. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) for details.

```
wait Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object. In other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call wait(0).
The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.
```

You may try passing a common object to individual thread say a String and synchronize on the same and call wait and notify using that object. like:

```
//thread1
synchronize(myString) {
    myString.wait();
}

//thread2
synchronize(myString) {
    myString.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Yeah maybe String can give some problem but this is the perfect answer i need. I get the point thank you. So maybe is just a dummy question but can i synchronizee the thread with the main ?

Comment: Nah i don't think so synchronizing on String (not interned string) is bad idea. It's immutable (nothing to do it over here) and can be shared across same instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing messages, so try using the java.util.concurrent classes.  Create a LinkedBlockingQueue common to both threads and use the put() and take() methods to pass the message.

This avoids using synchronization and blocks if no messages are available to read or no space is available to put a message.  Different classes give different behaviours if this is not exactly what you require.